# Updating label after a delay (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to achieve something pretty basic : I have a label with "Hello" as text, and I want, after 3 seconds, to change it to "World". The issue is that the tkinter created window only opens after the 3 seconds, with "World" (hello is never displayed).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("bruh")
root.geometry("1080x720")

def update():
    label.config(text= "World")

label = tk.Label(root, text = "hello", font = ("Consolas", 40), width = 1080, height = 720)
label.pack()
label.after(3000, update())
root.mainloop()
```

I'm new to tkinter and don't know what i'm doing wrong. Thanks !

Comment: You don't need the brackets after `update` within the after function. Make the line be: `label.after(3000, update)`

Comment: Do `label.after(3000, update)`.  If you *call* `update()` inside that expression, it will already have happened.

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to enter a parameter in update function ?  Like update (txt): label.config(text=txt)